# setTimeout as callback on react setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

code:

```
setTimeout(() => {
                this.setState((state, props) => ({
                  activateLightColorForRed: true
                }), () => {
                  setTimeout(
                    this.setState((state, props) => ({
                      activateLightColorForRed: false
                    })), 3000);  
                });
                red.play()
              }, 3000);
```

when there's no callback on react setstate it's working but I need to set activateLightColorForYellow to false after 3 seconds. if i use setstate outside setTimeout, setstate is not working. help?

Comment: removing the callback on setstate. then below setTimeOut(the parent?), after 3 seconds it'll be evaluated. right? but setstate don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have a syntax error. Missing an arrow function on second setTimeout.

Try this please;

```
setTimeout(()=> {
  this.setState((state, props) => ({ activateLightColorForRed: true }), () => {
    setTimeout(()=> {
      this.setState(()=> ({ activateLightColorForRed: false }))
    }, 3000);
    red.play();
  })
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `setState`'s callback is there for you to be sure the state has really been changed.
This is a small example of chained `setTimout`:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      title: "click me"
    };

    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }

  onClick(e) {
    this.setState({ title: "value 1" }, () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ title: "value 2" }, ()=>{
          setTimeout(()=>{
            this.setState({title: 'value 3'})
          },1500);
        });
      }, 1000);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div onClick={this.onClick}>{this.state.title}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```